# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT DISTINCT LED.IDX As IDX, CORPCODE, UNITTYPECODE, UPPERFORMATIONCODE, FORMATIONCODE, LED.UNITCODE As UNITCODE,LED.STORECODE As STORECODE, LED.SECTIONNO As SECTIONNO, LED.PARTNO As PARTNO, "
            sql &= " LED.BATCHNO As BATCHNO, UNITITEMCATEGORYCODE, LEDGERDATE, ENTITLEMENT, HOLDING, SURPLUS, SHORTAGE, COSTHOLDING, COSTENTITLEMENT, INITIALSTOCK, EMPLOYQTY, FIGHTQTY, ITEMAGE1, ITEMAGE2, ITEMAGE3,"
            sql &= " ITEMAGE4, LED.BAH_BEREK, LED.JENIS_BEREK, JPTD_NO, LASTUPDATE, LED.ITEMTYPECODE As ITEMTYPECODE, LED.TOOLTYPECODE As TOOLTYPECODE, LED.PAKAIBHGCODE, LED.PAKAICODE, ITEMNIDX, LED.CREATEID As CREATEID, "
            sql &= " LED.UPDATEID As UPDATEID, LED.CREATEDATE As CREATEDATE, LED.UPDATEDATE As UPDATEDATE, "
            sql &= " USERID, RANKCODE, SERVICENO, USERNAME, DESIGNATIONCODE, PASSWORD, "
            sql &= " 'OPER' AS GROUPCODE,5 AS ACESSID, 0 AS STATUS "
            sql &= " FROM (LEDGER AS LED) "
            sql &= " LEFT JOIN NUSER   On NUSER.USERID = LED.UPDATEID   WHERE (1=1)   "
            If condation <> "" Then
                sql += condation
            End If
            sql &= " UNION SELECT DISTINCT LED.IDX As IDX, CORPCODE, UNITTYPECODE, UPPERFORMATIONCODE, FORMATIONCODE, LED.UNITCODE As UNITCODE, LED.STORECODE As STORECODE, LED.SECTIONNO As SECTIONNO, LED.PARTNO As PARTNO, "
            sql &= " LED.BATCHNO As BATCHNO, UNITITEMCATEGORYCODE, LEDGERDATE, ENTITLEMENT, HOLDING, SURPLUS, SHORTAGE, COSTHOLDING, COSTENTITLEMENT, INITIALSTOCK, EMPLOYQTY, FIGHTQTY, ITEMAGE1, ITEMAGE2, ITEMAGE3,"
            sql &= " ITEMAGE4, LED.BAH_BEREK, LED.JENIS_BEREK, JPTD_NO, LASTUPDATE, LED.ITEMTYPECODE As ITEMTYPECODE, LED.TOOLTYPECODE As TOOLTYPECODE, LED.PAKAIBHGCODE, LED.PAKAICODE, ITEMNIDX, LED.CREATEID As CREATEID, "
            sql &= " LED.UPDATEID As UPDATEID, LED.CREATEDATE As CREATEDATE, LED.UPDATEDATE As UPDATEDATE,"
            sql &= " ('' AS USERID), ('' AS RANKCODE),('' AS SERVICENO),('' AS USERNAME),('' AS DESIGNATIONCODE), ('' AS PASSWORD), 'OPER',5 , STATUS "
            sql &= " FROM LEDGER_HISTORY LED WHERE (1=1) "
```

error is Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '('' AS USERID)'.
Can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct.  The problem is the parentheses.

This syntax is not appropriate for SQL:

```
SELECT ('' AS USERID)
```

However, this is:

```
SELECT ('') AS USERID
```

Or just:

```
SELECT '' AS USERID
```

You have the same problem with `FROM (LEDGER AS LED)`.

Comment: thank you very much.. but it still doesn't work.. once i did , this error came out :The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.